# How to group certain items in a list together - Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am asking if there is a way to group certain items in a list together to just make them one item. For example:

If I have a list `[5,"*",6,7]`, how can I group the `6` and `7` to make the number `67`, so that the list now looks like ["5","*", "67" ]?

Comment: Please give more explanations. What do you want to group ? Only numbers ? Following what rules ? Group to the right ? Group to the left ?

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but by looking at your questions I really think that you should take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), understand [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions (which get more chances to be answered) and always try to provide [minimal, reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you want to achieve (even if it doesn't work, you've to show your efforts: StackOverflow is not a "how do I do this" service). Finally, always search and *study* the documentation of the framework/api you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to group items together by their *type*. That is a function of [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> It generates a break or new group every time the value of the key function changes...

so you can use `type` to differ between the original list items of type `string` and `integer`.

```
from itertools import groupby

flat = [5,"*",6,7]

groups = []
f = groupby(flat,key=type)
for k, g in groupby(flat, key=type):
    groups.append(''.join(str(x) for x in list(g))) # Store group items as a joined list
print (groups)
```

Result:

```
['5', '*', '67']
```